# SUMIF INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to look up and sum up values on a another excel sheet where the sum up values are with certain criterias in a row.

Example below where:

criteria 1=date in Column D,

criteria 2= "SUB" or "RED" in column F.

I am not sure why my formula does not work at the sum stage:

[image]

Comment: please clarify what the desired output is and how/why your current formula is not delivering the output you need
Include a sample dataset and the formula(s) in your question

Comment: I need to sum up values in the blue range by looking up data in the yellow range by criteria (date & type). In J12 I am expecting 452,317.76, because there are 2 values for the 01/01//018 in the yellow range, a SUB and a RED. (226,158.88 x 2). I do not know why my formula does not work.

Comment: Also, I need to do it with INDEX MATCH because the underlying data is in another excel sheet and I cannot have it open all the time. with INDEX MATCH, you can have the underlying excel closed.

Comment: not sure why you are checking on type, as your explanation of the expected output is just summing it by date (in disregards of type).

Comment: btw, did you do Ctrl+Shft+Enter to make it an array formula?

Comment: yes :) does not make a difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Date]=[@LookupDate])*(Table1[Type]={"RED","SUB"})*Table1[Value])`